# Saving images from excel with names from adjacent cell

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel sheet with a productName column(A) and a productImage column (B) - I want to save the images in column B with the names from column A

I found this code on stack:

```
import re
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32com.client as win32

FILE = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\so\53994108\logo.xlsx'
CELLS = [(4, 5, 'F'), (3, 3, 'D')]

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(FILE)
for i, worksheet in enumerate(workbook.Sheets):
    row = CELLS[i][0]
    while True:
        name = worksheet.Cells(row, CELLS[i][1]).Value
        if not name:
            break
        name = re.sub(r'\W+ *', ' ', name)
        rng = worksheet.Range('{}{}'.format(CELLS[i][2], row))
        rng.CopyPicture(1, 2)
        im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
        im.save('{}.jpg'.format(name))
        row += 1

    cannot figure out the variable CELLS = in this answer.
```

Comment: reply@alderven - Can you please clarify the CELLS = [(4,5,'F'), (3,3,'D')]? Would really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: @stovfl returns F4

Comment: `CELLS` is of type `list` of `tuple`. Therefore, if `i == 0` you get with `CELLS[i]` => `(4,5,'F')`. `CELLS[i][2]` gives you the third, 0-based, item of the `tuple` which is `F`. I feel, the simpler approach for you ist: `name = worksheet.Cells(row, 1).Value` and `rng = worksheet.Range('{}{}'.format('B', row))`